# Avoiding echo of slash command for in_channel responses

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

i'm creating a really small slash command for my channel right now. I send the command to a PHP script using HTTPS 200, manipulate it and send it back as JSON payload, basically like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$text = $_POST['text'];

if ($text === "keyword") $answer = "Hello World";
else $answer = "Nothing in here";

$response = array(
  'response_type' => 'in_channel',
  'text' => $answer,
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Now I don't want to post the intial slash commend in the channel as already mentioned in the title but only the answer of the server should be visible for everyone in the channel. I can't find a suitable article for this, so I ask myself: Is it even possible?

Anybody have an idea?

**Edit:**
I dont want that slack also post my command as message. So that only the second message is post in the channel:
[see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMOKn.png)

**Update:**
I have now implemented the suggestion of Erik Kalkoken but I don't get a signal from the curl function. I also successfully checked if my webserver supports the curl functions. My code now looks like this (the code has been reduced to the necessary):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array(
  'response_type' => 'in_channel',
  'text' => "> \\M2\Kunden\_Tutorial"
);

echo json_encode(array('text' => 'One moment...'));

$ch = curl_init($_POST['response_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Working Solution:**
After taking Erik Kalkoken's advice into account again, it still didn't work. Which doesn't mean that he said something wrong. On the contrary, I forgot something. I found out that my $response array needs to be encoded as json string. Below you can see a working version. Thanks to Erik Kalkoken!

```
    <?php
    $response = array(
      'response_type' => 'in_channel',
      'text' => '> \\M2\Kunden\_Tutorial'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['response_url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: `str_replace('\\', '', $text)`? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: okay and what should i do with it? i can even say 'text' => '' to return an empty text. But my question is: How to prevent that the initial slash command is posted in the channel aswell?

Comment: Remove the command from the text? You can do it with `str_replace` if it's always the same command, or `preg_replace` for a regex. Either I don't understand your question, or the answer is really as simple as I'm writing :)

Comment: I mean: If i write "/mycommand Some Text" then Slack post "/mycommand Some Text" as a normal message from me and additional the answer from the external Server as seperate message. But i want only to display the answer from the server.

Comment: Yeah you echo the command you posted right back? That's what the `$text` contains?

Comment: Argh sorry :D between $text = and the $response = variable the text is changing completely. I will update my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Loek No, the command is automatically echoed back to the user by Slack. Its not done in his script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `response_type` set to `in_channel` its standard behavior for slash commands to echo your slash command. This usually makes sense, so people in that channel can see that a slash command was issues before they see its result.

There is no direct way to turn this echo feature off, but there is a simple workaround.

Instead of replying directly to the Slack request, send your response as new request to the `response_url`, which you got from Slack in the initial request. Then you only get your response in the channel and the slash command itself will not be echoed.

Btw. this behavior is also explained in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_response_url) in the section "Sending delayed responses":

> As with immediate response messages, you can include the response_type field. However, when you use a value of in_channel with this delayed method, the original text that invoked the command is not included.

I would recommend using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to send the request to Slack.

**Edit after question has been updated with curl call**

You are still returning a direct response to the Slack request, which is causing Slack to echo the user command. You must not return anything except 200 OK (which your PHP script will do automatically). So please remove this line:

`echo json_encode(array('text' => 'One moment...'));`

I would also advise to include the correct content header in the curl call by adding this line:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);`

The `header()` php command in the beginning does not affect the curl call and can be removed too btw.

Comment: i read the documentation and tested it today. but i cant get it to work. should i update my question with the new code or how should i go on?

Comment: I tested it and I can confirm that it works. so yes, please update your question with your latest code, so that people can help you get it working.

Comment: I updated my answer to point out how to get your code working as intended.

Comment: Yep your right, but also the $response should be encoded as json string. You helped a lot! Thank you